# The meaning of the ending of "Riddick" (2013)

Tags: riddick-franchise, riddick-2013

At the very end of the movie [Riddick (2013)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1411250/), Riddick asks the question:

> Is Vaako alive or dead?

And gets the following answer:

> Both.

I don't understand the meaning of the end at all. How should I interpret this answer and the whole conclusion of the movie.

Comment: The direct answer to my question is somewhat hidden in linked one, but after all... this indeed is a dupe. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I agree with removing this question as a dupe.  It basically means that a future person searching for the answer to this question will have to know to find and click on "Did Riddick make the trip the the Underverse" instead.  Then, after reading that question and finding that it does not ask about Vaako being alive or dead, they will need to still choose to read the answer, and find the thing they're looking for at the end of the answer's last paragraph.  If SFFSE is to function as a source of information for anyone but the initial inquirer, this is not optimal.

Comment: @MishaR SFFSE has long had the policy to close question when the answer can be found as the answer to another question.

Comment: @MishaR But this question will not be removed nor its audience will be reduced. It is available as every other question here, if I am not mistaken. The only thing that marking this as dupe means that: (a) there will be no answers accepted and (b) it will be linked to an actual source of information (the other question / answer). From my perspective (as a data / knowledge seeker) nothing changes. Future reader looses nothing, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @trejder If the dupe isn't removed, then that's fine.  My understanding has always been that closed questions are eventually removed, but reading the policy it looks like some dupes are left open (probably at the discretion of whomever is in charge of that decision).  This still leaves the issue that the answers in linked question can be edited at any time, without being held accountable for answering linked dupes, so I think a linked dupe should copy the answering part, and maybe have a comment pointing the reader to its location within the answers.

Comment: @trejder ...To be fair, making answering text part of the dupe might belong to the longer ongoing dupe-related SFFSE strife.